# Tomcat server will not start after added ip address in server.xml

Tags: tomcat, connector, server.xml

I added ip address in tomcat server.xml file to replace localhost with ip address. The change is,

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8090" address="" protocol="HTTP/1.1"      redirectPort="8443"/>
```

After i added the address parameter, the server will not started.

Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: What error do you get while try to start tomcat?

Comment: The error is "Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor."

Comment: i also increased timeout value. but no use.

Comment: May be you are missing some parameters which <connector> tag need.. Please verify again

Comment: Or do one more thing revert your change and try again to start tomcat as it woked before change ip address. And if it's working try find another way to.change ip address

Comment: If i remove the address parameter the server work properly.

Comment: What do you think that address="" means?

Comment: You can't add blank address value